# Does -[NSManagedObject willTurnIntoFault] disable KVO notifications?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

I have a NSManagedObject (person) that has several observers registered to a nested unmanaged property (person.address.street, address is unmanaged, i.e. not defined in Core Data). When the managed object gets faulted, I call

```
person.address = nil
```

in willTurnIntoFault to clear my unmanaged property. However, KVO does not remove the observers it registered for address to get notified of changes to 'street', although address is KVO compliant. Address gets deallocated, and I get a warning that it still has observers registered to it.

The only reason I can figure out is that willTurnIntoFault disables KVO notifications. Is this the case? Is there a workaround for this.

Thanks,
Jochen

Answer (score 1):

Jochen,

I see this same behaviour as part of managed object context merge processing (via mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:).  For "updated" objects in the merge user info, core data faults the "local" context's object and then performs a merge against the "remote" context's object.

If, as part of didTurnIntoFault: handling, I release my unmanaged property (which is very simple and definitely KVO compliant), the error appears.  Interestingly, it only seems to happen with "nested" unmanaged properties.  I have many other unmanaged properties as part of my managed objects which are simple objects (NSNumber, NSString etc), and these can be released as part of didTurnIntoFault: handling without any issues.  It's only when properties >= 2 levels deep are being observed within the unmanaged property that I see the problem.

I'm not sure if you have found a solution or not yet (I'd be very interested in hearing how you've progressed with this), but I have found a work-around. I leave my unmanaged property allocated within the faulted object and only deallocate it during prepareForDeletion.

```
-(void) performInventoryItemObjectSetup
{
    if ([self unitsManager] == nil) {
        [self setUnitsManager:[[[BTUnitsManager alloc] init] autorelease]];
    }
    ...
}

-(void) performInventoryItemObjectCleanup
{
    ...
}

/********************/

-(void) awakeFromInsert
{
    //NSLog(@"InventoryItem: awakeFromInsert");
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    [self performInventoryItemObjectSetup];
}

-(void) awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags
{
    //NSLog(@"InventoryItem: awakeFromSnapshotEvents: 0x%lx", flags);

    [super awakeFromSnapshotEvents:flags];

    if (flags & NSSnapshotEventUndoDeletion) {
        [self performInventoryItemObjectSetup];
    }
}

-(void) awakeFromFetch
{
    //NSLog(@"InventoryItem: awakeFromFetch");
    [super awakeFromFetch];
    [self performInventoryItemObjectSetup];
}

-(void) didTurnIntoFault
{
    //NSLog(@"InventoryItem: didTurnIntoFault");
    [self performInventoryItemObjectCleanup];
    [super didTurnIntoFault];
}


-(void) prepareForDeletion
{
    NSLog(@"InventoryItem: prepareForDeletion");
    [self setUnitsManager:nil];
    [super prepareForDeletion];
}
```

I suspect more people will run into this issue as more and more Core Data apps are released with iCloud support which requires this kind of merging as part of NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification handling.  Either that or we'll find out what we're doing wrong :-).

Cheers,
Michael.

Comment: Just realized I haven't tried putting the work-around in prepareForDeletion yet.  I'll give that a try tomorrow. If it also works, I'd class that as a better work-around for the problem than overriding dealloc.

Comment: Using prepareForDeletion works fine and is a better solution to working around this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can using a technic, which describe in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/FoundationOlder.html 
To avoid this error, u can using a different keypath in binding, which will include entity, with KVO compliant.
Please look to "Support for Debugging of Bad KVO Compliance" and "Advice for Fixing One Kind of Bad KVO Compliance" notes.

Comment: Which technique do you refer to in the document? I couldn't find anything in there that refers to this problem except maybe using setKeys:triggerChangeNotificationsForDependentKey:, but this is deprecated.